# Norm of linear map $f:R^n \rightarrow R^m$ from its matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Assume $f:R^n \rightarrow R^m$ is a linear map. Therefore, $f$ can be represented as a matrix. Namely, for any $x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in R^n$
\begin{align}
f(x)= (x_1,...,x_n)
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & ... & a_{1m}  \\
...    & ... & ...    \\
a_{n1} & ... & a_{nm}
\end{pmatrix}
=xA
\end{align}
I think the matrix $A$ contains all imformation of $f$. Define the norm of $f$ as
$$
\|f\| = \sup_{x\in R^n} \frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}
$$
where $|x|$ is the  Euclidean norm. Therefore, there should be a way to calculate the $\|f\|$ from $A$. But I can't find what of $A$ equals to $\|f\|$. For example, the eigenvalue of $A$ is not $\|f\|$ (in fact, $A$ may not has eigenvalue, since may $n\not = m$).

PS: I have a little algebra knowledge. Only a little   linear algebra I know.

Comment: If you write the elements of $\mathbb R^k$ as column vectors, and $A$ is the $m \times n$ matrix whose $j$-th column is $f(e_j)$ (where $e_j$ is the vector whose $j$-th entry is $1$ and every other entry is $0$), then $f(x) = Ax$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$, and $$\|f\| = \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$$ which equals $\inf\{c \in [0,\infty) : \|Ax\| \leq c\|x\| \textrm{ for all } x \in \mathbb R^n\}$ (easy exercise). Now, having observed this, you can delve into this *matrix norm* [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/matrixnorm.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\|f\|$ equals the square root of the largest eigenvalue of the (positive semi-definite) matrix $A^\top A$, which - at the same time - is the largest singular value of $A$.

Comment: Thanks, where I can find the proof ?

Comment: You have$$\|f\|^2 = \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|^2 = \sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Ax,Ax\rangle = \sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle A^\top Ax,x\rangle.$$The rest follows from the MinMax-theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem

Comment: @lanse7pty This follows easily from the fact that $\lVert A^TA \rVert = \lVert A \rVert^2$ and that $A^TA$ is orthonormally diagonalizable with nonnegative eigenvalues since $A^TA$ is positive semi-definite.